# Querying Contentful local JSON results in JavaScript client side?

Tags: json, contentful

I am using Contentful CMS - when my JavaScript app loads, I retrieve all the articles/entries during app initialization. I then want to query this local json object without doing futher Http calls to Contentful

Each entry of the 'items' array will have 'id' links to categories/authors/assets etc which will be in the returned Json.

Is there a JavaScript library or API I can use to query this Contentful json data locally on the client side?

Comment: The Contentful JS library (npm) has a createClient() with return a Client API helper - there was resolveLinks: true property - I was watching the returned JSON instead of looking at the repsonse from the helper function! I thought the links were resolved server side and added to the JSON, but it's done in the JS client side helper functions. Also found an npm module contentful-resolve-response that is pretty much what I was after

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to look at [normalizr](https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr) for that. The idea is to transform JSON into something that you can access by entity type + entity id, so it 'feels'  more like querying a relational database.